# Is my stochastic process wide sense-stationary?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

If I have a process Xn that is made of two sequences of independent random variables. For n being even , Xn is either +1 or -1 with probability 1/2 , but for n odd , Xn is either 1/5 or -5 with probabilities 25/26 and 1/26 respectively.
**How could I prove it is or it is not wide sense-stationary?**

side question : 
*I know that the distribution is different , but if the probabilities where the same , would the distributions be considered the same? (meaning: +1 or -1 with probability 1/2 for even numbers , and 1/5 or -5 with probability 1/2 for odd numbers ) or to say the distributions are the same it should be : +1 or -1 with probability 1/2 for even numbers, and 1 or -1 with probability 1/2 for odd numbers)*

Comment: Wide sense stationary means that the mean and autocovariance matrix don’t change under time translations. Here that just is whether the mean and variance of the two distributions are the same. Your altered example has different means for the two distributions, so they certainly aren’t the same distribution  and also your altered example is not wide sense stationary.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Why is it that here is whether the mean and variance are the same?

Comment: since they’re iid there’s no correlation, so all you have to worry about is mean and variance if you translate time. Translating by an even number leads to the same distribution, so you just need to check if translating by an odd number leads to the same mean and variance. I can see they’re both mean zero, so you just need to check if they’re the same variance.

Comment: Notice that if it comes out to be the same, this shows that wide sense stationary does not imply stationary... this is clearly not stationary since the distribution changes time to time.